# vscode devcontainer, how to run x86 container in M1?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A few days ago I created a devcontainer and it was running intel arch even though I'm on M1. I decided to rebuild it today and now I'm getting an ARM image instead of Intel..

Evidenced by

> Support for ARM64 is in preview.

All good and well BUT the software I'm running in the dev container requires Intel. How can I revert to using the intel image? More broadly, for the future, how can I choose whether a devcontainer runs ARM, Intel, or "matches host"?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this working? I'm trying to build x86_64 images on an M1 Mac but haven't had luck yet.

Comment: @ascrookes : while I never revisited this topic and opted not to use devcontainers, I can offer some insight about building x86_64 images on an M1 Mac. You can pass the --platform flag to any pull/build/run command, and Docker Desktop (as well as Rancher Desktop) will use that arch if available, e.g. :    `docker pull --platform linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04`